# Practice different grammar forms

Tags: discussion

Before asking my question, let me set up the context.
I'm a non-native English speaker. However, I have used the language for almost all my life. I went to a British school, and I have lived in Australia. Thus, I can say with much confidence that my level of English is fairly good. Nevertheless, my grammar is far from perfect, and I need to take it to the next level because of my job. For that purpose, I took an online grammar English course from where I learned a myriad of rules, and I want to put them into practice. So now I ask the question. Is there a place where I can see paragraphs and not just simple sentences that are analyzed grammatically? For instance, where they point out each part of the sentence and its function, including if it is an adverb clause, noun clause, reduced noun clause, nonfinite clause, complex sentence, etc.

I will appreciate any help. I have been looking for a site that fulfills my requirements, but I have failed so far.

Kind regards!

P.S.: If you want to correct any of my writing, please do! It would help me a lot!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Site rules [Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ask that you first search for answers before asking here. If you had then you would have found [this](http://www.examenglish.com/KET/KET_grammar.htm). If after searching you still can't find what you want, state what you have found and why it falls short.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 This isn't responsive to the question.  He's done this kind of work.

Comment: @Xanne The [this](http://www.examenglish.com/KET/KET_grammar.htm) wasn't responsive? How do you figure? Do you disagree with the statement that you shouldn't ask simple questions that a basic web search can find?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56: I don't think grammar tests ever properly teach usage *in context* which one really needs. This can be answered by people here based on their experience, and I think asking it here leads one to admit that possibility. Admittedly, that's not the direct answer but I think it could be one.

Mine: literature. Read the masters (Tolkien, Graves, Gibbon), and if their sentences make sense in usage, that's good. If their grammar doesn't, go through it until you can explain the usage. Replicate both. If you want to know the sentence parts, work through it yourself in every case.

Comment: I am an Academic Games player, and one of the games, LinguiSHTIK (in which I am a two-time national champion), has taught me all I know about grammar. The Officials' Manual is an excellent source of advanced grammar stuffs. http://agloa.org/wp-content/uploads/LingOfficialsManual1617.pdf

Comment: @gktscrk How about [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com)?  Write and then have grammarly check it.  You as a good as Grammarly when it doesn't offer any corrections. This kind of discussion strikes me as more suited to [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).But there are plenty of native speakers that could benefit from improved grammar.

Comment: @Scrooble Interesting ....

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56: Good idea; why I didn't think of it is my preference for Opera which I believe you can't use it with. I have tried the extension once though. I imagine other people (more in tune with Chrome) like it a bit more than I do

Comment: First, your level of English is better than "fairly good"!  Second, the last sentence of your first paragraph is not a complete sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The only site I've found helpful in that regard is http://1aiway.com/nlp4net/services/enparser/

It diagrams sentences and labels the parts and functions. It's far from perfect, but it does help to understand sentence structure.

Another site that helps is http://www.german-latin-english.com/diagrams.htm

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your response! I will check both sites!